# python aboutdialog space between program name/version and logo

Tags: python, pygtk

please how can i set space between program name/version and logo in this code? I am using pygtk. thanks

```
about = gtk.AboutDialog()
about.set_program_name("name")
about.set_version("0.0.1")
about.set_logo(gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("file.png"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hacky I suppose, but this works:

```
import gtk

about = gtk.AboutDialog()
about.set_program_name("name")
about.set_version("0.0.1")
about.set_logo(gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("file.png"))
about.show()

vbox = about.get_children()[0].get_children()[0]  # vbox containing everything but the buttons at the bottom
label = vbox.get_children()[1] # Label containing name and version
alignment = gtk.Alignment(xalign=0.5, yalign=0.5)
alignment.set_padding(100, 0, 0, 0)
alignment.show()

vbox.remove(label)
alignment.add(label)
vbox.add(alignment)
vbox.reorder_child(alignment, 1)  # Put it back in the correct order, rather than below the URL and stuff

gtk.main()
```

Change 100 to the number of pixels you want to add between the logo and the program name.

Comment: cool, thank you Jeremy! It looks goood. Only one more thing - texts was centered and now first line is centered to the left and other lines to center. How can center first line (name+version) to center? thanks in advance

Comment: You have to center the contents of the `gtk.Alignment`. I edited the code to do this.